# MySQL #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, innodb, easyphp

I'm begginer here, all what i'm trying to do is insert into a table field which is a foreign key, please take a look at this two tables :

Table **Categorie**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categorie` (
    `id_cat` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
    `nom_cat` varchar(20) NOT NULL,   
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_cat`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and table **Annonce**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `annonce` (
  `id_annonce` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `titre` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tarif` float NOT NULL,
  `deplacement` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `date_creation` date NOT NULL,
  `date_expiration` date NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id_cat` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_annonce`),
  KEY `id_cat` (`id_cat`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

After linking the foreign key id_cat manually (ON UPDATE SET NULL ON DELETE CASCADE) that's how the db looks like

[image: DB designer]

and after inserting data into Categorie table it looks like this

[image: Categorie table]

But unfortunately i couldn't execute this query :

```
INSERT INTO annonce (id_annonce, titre, description, tarif, deplacement, 
                    date_creation, date_expiration,id_cat) 
VALUES('','anything','anything',2,3,'2017-04-01','2017-04-01',2)
```

the error says :

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
>   (`lametcom`.`annonce`, CONSTRAINT `annonce_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_cat`) 
>   REFERENCES `annonce` (`id_cat`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Can anyone help please and so sorry about my poor English i hope you can understand what i mean

Comment: inserting an empty string into a not null column. omit that column and let the auto increment worry about it :`INSERT INTO annonce (titre, description, tarif, deplacement, 
                    date_creation, date_expiration,id_cat) 
VALUES('anything','anything',2,3,'2017-04-01','2017-04-01',2)`

Comment: Thanks for tip i woldn't know it works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreign key constraint is wrong. You have

```
FOREIGN KEY id_cat REFERENCES annonce (id_cat)
```

but it should be:

```
FOREIGN KEY id_cat REFERENCES categorie (id_cat)
```

The table name in the foreign key constraint has to be the table you're linking to.

Comment: Thanks you very much, i felt so stupid making this type of faults :D